# Cppcheck Possible null pointer dereference:

Tags: c++, cppcheck

i am just using cppcheck the code is working properly just cppcheck gives this errors.

```
void WorkerThread(WorkBuffer* m_buffer)
{
    std::cout << "Thread : " << m_buffer->m_id << ".....Starting" << std::endl;

    if (NULL == m_buffer)
        std::cout << "Thread : " << m_buffer->m_id << "......work buffer is null" << std::endl;


    while(!shut_down_flag)
    {
        int k = 0;
        //Sleep(1);
        SleepSystemUsec(100000);
        std::cout << "Thread : " << m_buffer->m_id << "....in while loop" << std::endl;
    } // of while(!shut_down_flag)

    std::cout << "Thread : " << m_buffer->m_id << ".....Request from main thread so ending working thread ...." << std::endl;
};
```

error : : Possible null pointer dereference: m_buffer - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null.

Comment: More code please & CPPCheck command line options supplied.

Comment: You're checking if `m_buffer` is `NULL` *after* you've already used it. The message is pointing out (correctly) that if it *could* be `NULL` (and if not, why are you checking?) you should find out *before* using it in the line above.

Comment: @PaulRoub: That should be an **answer** not a **comment**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (NULL == m_buffer)
```

makes sure `m_buffer` is `NULL`, and then you derefence it with

```
std::cout << "Thread : " << m_buffer->m_id << "......work buffer is null" << std::endl;
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

this, which is only legal if `m_buffer` is *not* `NULL` (more precisely, only if it points to a correctly constructed `WorkBuffer`).

If `NULL` is a possible input for your function, you need to check for it *before* the very first dereference and then either make it point to something valid or leave the function without dereferencing.

Comment: couldn get what you said. would you please provide some details

Comment: @user3521035 Could you be a little bit more specific with what you don't get?

Comment: In fact, the cppcheck warning is for the previous `m_buffer->m_id << ".....Starting"` before the check. It doesn't spot this error.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well this is the same problem as the other one (covered by my *"check for it before the very first dereference "* remark): Either the pointer can be `NULL`, then check before you use it, or it cannot, then you never need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is your condition backwards:

> if `m_buffer` is `NULL`:
>     do things that dereference `m_buffer`
>   *(huh?!)*

but you have no checks on any of the other output statements.